# Can installing an unknown deb package using sudo dpkg be harmful?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, dpkg, deb

Let’s say I install a package using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb
```

then without running the package binaries I just remove it:

```
sudo dpkg -r package-name
```

Is there anything harmful that can happen in this process? 
For example, any malicious configuration script in the `.deb` file?  What are other possible threats that might happen?

Comment: I even once wrote a small .rpm file called "timebomb" that didn't contain any files and no install script, but an uninstall script effectively doing `rpm -rf /`. I didn't dare to test it, however…

Comment: Seems that I should read the whole documentation about creating `deb` packages to make sure what else can be happen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, packages can contain [“maintainer scripts”](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) which are run before and/or after installation. You can see the scripts, if any, by extracting the control archive from the package:

```
dpkg-deb --ctrl-tarfile package-name.deb > control.tar
tar tf control.tar
```

or, if you know you want to extract the control archive’s contents:

```
dpkg-deb -e package-name.deb package-control
```

(which places the extracted files in a directory named `package-control`).

They run as root and can do whatever the package author wants on your system.

You should really consider that installing a package is equivalent to granting the maintainer (and anyone else involved in the package’s maintenance and build) root access to your system. Who do you trust?

Comment: Thanks, so if I examine the script and if there was nothing suspicious with  that, I'm safe to go? actually there is only a `control` and `md5sum` file in `control.tar`.

Comment: The scripts can be ok and you will have binaries running as root...as usual install only things from trusted sources.

Comment: I can't get it, so while installing using `dpkg` there might be other binaries involved in installation process from package? (lets say there is no pre or post install script in `deb` file). PS: package is from kde.org. I'm just really paranoia ;)

Comment: @StephenKitt The package may install files in locations which are run automatically, such as `/etc/cron.d` (and many others).

Comment: `dpkg-deb --control` to just extract the control archive directly

Comment: @muru thanks; I went for a two-step approach because there’s not much point extracting the control archive if listing it shows there are no maintainer scripts.

Answer (score 9):

Even forgetting maintainer scripts, the package might install a Cron script that runs every minute, and the minute might tick over in-between you installing and uninstalling the package.

Or it might install a program at `/bin/python` for example (which will be used in preference to the real `/usr/bin/python`) and then some background process might try to launch Python.

Or it might install a program at `/bin/dpkg` so that when you try to remove it you're actually just running it.

Comment: +1 for cron and dpkg. In Debian, packaged Python scripts specify `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` so their interpreter can’t be hijacked in the way you describe (but local scripts might use `env` and be vulnerable). A package could just replace Python though!

Comment: @StephenKitt I wasn't sure if a package could replace existing files, as that would make it difficult for dpkg to uninstall it correctly. Python scripts don't universally find Python through the shebang line - the calling program could also run `python whatever.py`.

Comment: There are (at least) two ways for a package to replace existing files: it can declare a `Replaces` relationship in its control file, and then it’s allowed to replace any file in the replaced package, or it can divert a file (but then it needs maintainer scripts to do that). Agreed on `python whatever.py`, at least for locally-installed programs (I think that would go against Debian policy, so I wouldn’t expect Debian packages to do that).

Comment: What about a service like apache? Doesn't it start automatically right upon installation?

Comment: @Calimo That's probably a maintainer script

Comment: @Calimo yes, the `postinst` maintainer script will start or restart the daemon after installation.